# Highlight p:datatable row by mouseover, but can not get the highlighted row value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, primefaces, jsf-2.2

This is a primefaces showcase on official website:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml

when you move your mouse over the datatable, and right click, you can not get the row object which you highlighted by mouse over, but if you really clicked specific row, then you right click, you can get the row object successfully.

I want to get the row object, and provide some functions in the context menu.

Is that mean there is no such an API that you can get row object by mouse over?

Comment: You want to use an event like `onmousedown` or `onmouseover` in your `dataTable`

Comment: yes, but it seems there is no such an api,  for example, we have <p:ajax event="rowSelect">, for the clicked row, you can use rowSelect event, but for mouse over, it not supported, when you try to use right click(the right click context menu implemented by myself, not broswer original right click context menu ), i can not get the object on the row when right click.

Comment: I agree with your comment think that for the right click you have to use some `javascript` code